# How to Disable Spring Data JPA’s default transaction behaviour?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I don’t want @Transactional which is written over SimpleJpaRepository of Spring jpa. I want to control transactionality on my own by annotating my service layer classes.
What I have tried:
enableDataTransaction=false
But It didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate in your services, the external transaction will be the current transaction for your method and Spring will ignore the internal ones because of their propagation rules 
If you wanna have more info about propagation:
https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/spring-transactional-cheat-sheet